# Backendless android dataquery callback function always calling handle fault method

Tags: android, backendless

Anyone who uses backendless.com as its backend please check out this.
Every time this code runs it goes to handlefault.I have tried everything can any one tell whats going wrong

```
String whereClause = "title = first";

BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();

dataQuery.setWhereClause(whereClause);

Backendless.Data.of(SavePost.class).find(dataQuery,

new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<SavePost>>() {

@Override

public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<SavePost> sp) {

if (sp != null) {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I got      something",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

 }

 @Override

 public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }

 });
```

Comment: What's the fault it gives you? I suspect you need quotes around `first`.

Comment: Thanks you were right

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the search term in the where clause, so:

```
String whereClause = "title = 'first'";
```